Image and metadata of mint created using Metaplex Core not showing up on Explorer and Solscan
  const genericFile = createGenericFile(fs.readFileSync("../../assets/token_voltio.png"), "token_voltio.png", { contentType: "image/png" });

  const [imageUri] = await umi.uploader.upload([genericFile]);

  const uri = await umi.uploader.uploadJson({
    name: "Voltio",
    symbol: "VLT",
    description: "Voltio is a project on Solana, decentralizing power generation for everyone in a net-zero and sustainable manner.",
    image: imageUri,
  })

  const assetSigner = generateSigner(umi);

  const { signature } = await create(umi, {
    asset: assetSigner,
    name: "Voltio",
    uri,
  }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

  console.log(`Transaction: ${getExplorerLink("tx", bs58.encode(signature), process.env.CLUSTER)}`)
  console.log(`Mint: ${getExplorerLink("address", assetSigner.publicKey, process.env.CLUSTER)}`)

Read through the docs for Core, and it says is uses an Asset Account (which is owned by the Metaplex Core program) instead of a typical SPL Mint Account. Is this why my metadata isn't directly visible on Explorer and Solscan (the latter is claimed to support Metaplex Core)?

What is your mint ID?

it seems like explorer and solscan currently have issues with showing Core Assets in devnet. Solana.fm is showing devnet core assets just fine.
In general solscan and explorer do support showing core image metadata, see these mainnet assets:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/3w2JBjnW61RmnPinLKHwDKHyMceEoNYo3HANH91tSKLH
https://solscan.io/token/3w2JBjnW61RmnPinLKHwDKHyMceEoNYo3HANH91tSKLH


